# Is it wise to store huge JSON array in mongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb

Is it wise to store pretty huge size (around million) `JSON Array` in a `collection` or document in mongoDB?

Does it impact performance?

If not what would be better alternative? I thought of maintaining as relational but thought not the right approach to do in NOSQL DB.

At high level, All that i need to query for size of the array at the moment. But had a look at the document size in mongoDB is limited to 16 MB.. Found here, docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents and hence I am confused

Comment: It all depends on how/whether you're going to use that data.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev at high level, All that i need to query for size of the array at the moment. But had a look at the document size in mongoDB is limited to 16 MB.. Found here, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents and hence I am confused